# "Output of image computation is too large" GEE Solutions

Tags: google-earth-engine, landtrendr

I am currently using the Landtrendr algorithm to plot time-series graphs of average NBR values for different levels of burn severity.

I am using the example 'LandTrendr Zonal Time Series Plotter' script provided, however I keep getting the error:

> Output of image computation is too large (6 bands for 2413581 pixels =
> 110.5 MiB > 80.0 MiB).
> If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter

I have added a titleScale parameter of the highest value (16) and have also increased the other scale value and this produces the error:

> Computed image is too large.

Is there a way to get around this so I can plot the graphs successfully?

```
    //#                                                                                                    #\\
    //#                      LANDTRENDR SOURCE AND FITTING ZONAL MEDIAN TIME SERIES                        #\\
    //#                                                                                                    #\\
    //########################################################################################################
    
    // author: Justin Braaten | jstnbraaten@gmail.com
    // website: https://github.com/eMapR/LT-GEE
    // about: this script will plot a time series of orginal and LandTrendr-fitted data
    //        for the area within a given geometry aggregated by the median function
    
    //########################################################################################################
    //##### INPUTS ##### 
    //########################################################################################################
    
    // get geometry stuff
    var aoi = fire_buffer
    
    // define years and dates to include in landsat image collection
    var startYear = 1985;    // what year do you want to start the time series 
    var endYear   = 2022;    // what year do you want to end the time series
    var startDay  = '01-01'; // what is the beginning of date filter | month-day
    var endDay    = '03-20'; // what is the end of date filter | month-day
    var index = 'NBR';
    var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'snow'];
    var summaryScale = 500;
    var runParams = { 
      maxSegments:            6,
      spikeThreshold:         0.9,
      vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
      preventOneYearRecovery: true,
      recoveryThreshold:      0.75,
      pvalThreshold:          0.05,
      bestModelProportion:    0.75,
      minObservationsNeeded:  6
    };
    
    var changeParams = {
      delta:  'gain',
      sort:   'greatest',
      year:   {checked:true, start:2007, end:2013},
      mag:    {checked:true,  value:100,  operator: '>', dsnr:false},
      dur:    {checked:false,  value:4,    operator: '<'},
      preval: {checked:true,  value:0,  operator: '>'},
      mmu:    {checked:true,  value:11},
    };
    
    //########################################################################################################
    //########################################################################################################
    //########################################################################################################
    
    // ----- GET/MAKE FUNCTIONS -----
    var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');
    
    var getSummary = function(img, geom, scale) {
      return img.reduceRegion({
       reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
       geometry: geom,
       scale: scale,
       maxPixels: 10e9,
       tileScale: 16
      });
    };
    
    //----- GET FITTED BAND STACK -----
    // run LandTrendr
    
    // add index to changeParams object
    changeParams.index = index;
    
    var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, index, [index], runParams, maskThese);
    
    // get the change map layers
    var changeImg = ltgee.getChangeMap(lt, changeParams);
    
    // clip the image
    var changeImg = changeImg.clip(aoi);
    
    // get the fitted NBR out
    var fitBandStack = ltgee.getFittedData(lt, startYear, endYear, index);
    
    //----- GET RAW BAND STACK -----
    // build annual surface reflectance collection (cloud and shadow masked medoid composite)
    var annualSRcollection = ltgee.buildSRcollection(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, maskThese);
    
    // transform the annual surface reflectance bands to whatever is in the bandList variable
    var indexCollection = ltgee.transformSRcollection(annualSRcollection, [index]);
    
    // transform image collection of NBR (from bandList) to a image band stack
    var rawBandStack = ltgee.collectionToBandStack(indexCollection, startYear, endYear);
    
    //----- GET YEAR BAND STACK -----
    var yearBandStack;
    var tmp;
    for(var yr = startYear; yr <= endYear; yr++){
      tmp = ee.Image(yr);
      tmp = tmp.select([0], [yr.toString()]);
      if(yr == startYear){
        yearBandStack = tmp;
      } else{
        yearBandStack = yearBandStack.addBands(tmp);
      }
    }
    
    var magnitude = changeImg.select('mag').multiply(0.001)
    
    var yod = changeImg.select('yod')
    
    // add year of detection mask to only focus on pixels for the right disturbance
    var yodmask = yod.lte(2009).and(yod.gte(2010));
    
    // select pixels for each severity
    var high_mask = magnitude.lt(1.30).and(magnitude.gte(0.66)).updateMask(yodmask);
    
    var m_high_mask = magnitude.lt(0.66).and(magnitude.gte(0.44)).updateMask(yodmask);
    
    var m_low_mask = magnitude.lt(0.44).and(magnitude.gte(0.27)).updateMask(yodmask);
    
    var low_mask = magnitude.lt(0.27).and(magnitude.gte(0.1)).updateMask(yodmask);
    
    //var mask = mask.updateMask(yodmask);
    
    var yearBandStack = yearBandStack.updateMask(high_mask); 
    var rawBandStack = rawBandStack.updateMask(high_mask); 
    var fitBandStack = fitBandStack.updateMask(high_mask); 
    
    //----- MAKE ARRAYS -----
    var yearSummary = getSummary(yearBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
    var rawSummary = getSummary(rawBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
    var fitSummary = getSummary(fitBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
    var chartArray = ee.Array.cat([rawSummary, fitSummary], 1);
    
    
    //----- PLOT THE TIME SERIES -----
    var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(chartArray, 0, yearSummary)
                  .setSeriesNames(['Original', 'Fitted'])
                  .setOptions({
                    hAxis: {
                      'title': 'Year',
                      'maxValue': startYear,
                      'minValue': endYear,
                      'format': '####'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                      'title': index,
                      'maxValue': 1000,
                      'minValue': -1000 
                    },
                    pointSize: 0,
                    lineSize: 2,
                });
    
    print(chart);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/12c29d06a2e8807e0c14f68cc378045d

Answer (score 0):

**1. Reduce the Number of Bands:**
If possible, consider reducing the number of bands in your computed image. Focus on including only the essential bands needed for your analysis or visualization.

**2. Spatial and Temporal Aggregation:**
Instead of processing the entire area at once, try spatially aggregating or reducing the resolution of your data.
Temporally aggregate data if you are working with time-series information.

**3. ROI Selection:**
Limit the geographical extent of your computation by selecting a smaller ROI if it aligns with your analysis requirements.

**4. Use Image Reducer:**
Utilize image reducer functions (e.g., reduceRegion, reduceRegionToImage) to summarize or aggregate the information within your region of interest. This can help in generating a smaller output.

`var reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(); var scale = 30; var reducedStats = yourImage.reduceRegion({ reducer: reducer, geometry: yourROI, scale: scale });`

Hope this helps!